# Resolve duplicate versions of dependency

Tags: java, maven, duplicates, dependencies

This has been very annoying. I have 2 projects, project `A` and `B`, `B` with dependency on `A` as a JAR file. So a 3rd library `X` in A has a dependency on another 3rd party library `Y`, the problem is maven resolves `Y` in project `A` to a version, but in project `B` to another version, like the following:

```
commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2 vs. commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
```

And the version below is specified in project `A`:

```
net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4
```

In the POM.xml of project `B`, there isn't really any explicitly specified version of dependencies.

In project `A`:

```
[INFO] +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
```

In project `B` that only introduces the dependency on `Y` because of `A`:

```
[INFO] +- A.jar
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
```

The ideal solution is to only make changes in `pom.xml` in project `B` to solve the duplicate versions dependency hell. Any idea? Thanks!

Is it possible to make project `B` inherit dependencies from `A.jar` instead of introducing those of its own.

## EDIT

In the end I found something that worked, so I'd just put it here in case someone may be facing the same problem later.

The key is to put the dependencies come with project A into exclusions, so maven won't just use the versions of libraries defined in project A, but work out a version based on the current context. Below is the example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wonderland</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- ... everything else to be excluded -->
    <exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Maven seems to be behaving as intended here, i.e. resolving the conflict by using the version declared in the POM.

Comment: The problem is that both versions of dependencies end up in the war. I know the two project can share a BOM to resolve the discrepancy, but unfortunately it is not an option here.

Comment: Which WAR? And what its POM? In `WEB-INF/lib` there cannot be duplicates.

Comment: Could you please show the whole dependency trees? There must be some kind of dependency mediation in the background. commons-beanutils is probably also referenced at some other (transitive) point.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The whole POM.xml is lengthy. Have added more info above to show the context.

Comment: And I checked thru the whole dependency tree, the "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib" is the only one that depends on "beanutils".

Comment: @Tunaki the war of project B (B.war)

Comment: What is the dependency in double here? The tree doesn't show it.

Comment: @KevinWang Somewhere, the version 1.8.0 of commons-beanutils must have been defined. Also the version 1.9.2. Please find those two places. It may be in the dependency tree, or in some dependencyMangement.

Comment: @Tunaki commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2 (dependency:tree output in project A)  vs. commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 (dependency:tree output in project B)

Comment: Please share both project A and project B's complete POM or dependency tree. The question details are incomplete.

Comment: @KevinWang Your EDIT is the wrong approach: If you want to set the version of a dependency, use <dependencyManagement>, not exclusions.

Comment: @JFMeier, I don't want to set specific version of a dependency, just want to avoid duplicate. I don't see dependency management is a solution in this case, as  I can only change project B alone.

Comment: The duplicates in your war indicate that your build is somehow broken. Of course, you might hack around it with excludes, but in the long run it might be a problem.

Comment: @JFMeier, I believe you also have experience working on some production systems that evolve over time with inheritance that one can't just change at free will. Engineers don't work in vacuum like physicists, they deal with reality and find a way to make it work. :-)

Comment: @KevinWang I admit that. But if your build script is broken at a very fundamental level, this will fire back someday. I also do "ugly" things in Maven, but after I understood what Maven is doing and why I need to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put the main points into an answer.

B is a war and depends on the jar A. So it inherits all the transitive dependencies of A.

`net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile` has actually a dependency on `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile` (I looked that up). So your project B correctly resolves this dependency (and puts it into the war).

The tree of project A shows a dependency of commons-beanutils on version 1.9.2. This version number must have come from some other place inside project A. It may be a dependencyManagement, it may be some other dependency. Track down where the version 1.9.2 comes from and you know more.

In any case, the war will only contain the version 1.8.0 and not 1.9.2 as you can never have two artifacts with same groupId/artifactId in one war.

Comment: thanks for the summary. the problem is the war does contains two versions of the same library, and for more than one library.

Comment: @KevinWang I bet against that. Please give me a detailed example of two artifacts with same groupId/artifactId which end up in the war.

Comment: OK, I give you one (unzip -l B.war):
    69409  12-08-2016 14:38   WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.1.jar
    62983  01-17-2017 17:36   WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar

Comment: And they have both groupId javax.activation?

Comment: And you are sure you made a clean before the build? (e.g. "clean install")

Comment: Thank you for asking. Yes, I did "clean package" every single time.

Comment: Then something _very strange_ is happening in your build. You should never have this kind of behaviour. I guess nobody can help you unless you provide your full pom.