# Duplicate class android.support.v4. found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting a dependency duplicate issue please help.

```
error details: "Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
```

Comment: Hi and congratulations on your first question in SO :) Your problem may have already been resolved earlier. Please pay attention on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/56029393/4417142, or provide a more complete stacktrace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve duplicate versions of dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700285/resolve-duplicate-versions-of-dependency)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Hi Guys, I managed to get my app working. I just updated my SDK and started the app from scratch ,opied all my code to new project and voila!.  Thanks for the input.